# Redirecting Entire Site with Zeus

Tags: zeus

I am trying to redirect an entire site that is on a Zeus server. I have only managed to successfully redirect the homepage. Other pages are coming up with "Page not found". Here's the code I used:

```
    match URL into $ with ^\/$
if matched
set OUT:Location = http://www.mentalhealthreform.ie/
set OUT:Content-Type = text/html
set RESPONSE = 301
set BODY = Moved
goto END
endif
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

you might want to try:

```
RULE_0_START:
match IN:Host into $ with currentsite\.co\.uk$
if matched then
match URL into $ with ^/(.*)$
    set OUT:Location = http://www.newsite.com/$1
    set OUT:Content-Type = text/html
    set RESPONSE = 301
    set BODY = Moved
goto END
endif
RULE_0_END:
```

This should match the page request on the current site and append to the new.  Our servers are now on Apache, but I do remember the difficulties in doing things with Zeus.